# Read and edit an excel template using the Axlsx gem?

Tags: ruby, excel, axlsx

I have an excel template I'd like to load and then edit in ruby. I've looked into the Axlsx gem but I don't see a way to read in a file and edit? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I have ever seen that is similar to that is this repo/gem.

https://github.com/asanghi/excel_rails

I've never used it personally, so ymmv!

Comment: Axlsx is an awesome gem. Currently, it just allows to create and render the file. I am considering extending the gem to have it read xls files and edit them too. Do share your thoughts.